# Not able to link a "picture library" to a "picture library slideshow web part"

Tags: picture-library, slidelibrary

I've created a picture library with about 23 pictures and the images are all uploaded.  I want them to rotate on a page with a "picture library slideshow web part" but when I try to select "picture library" there's no options.  I've tried refreshing the page, deleting and re-adding the web part.  Re-uploading the images to a NEW picture library and still nothing. I'm not sure if I'm missing something to make the Picture Library visible to web parts but Google isn't turning anything up.

Please let me know if I'm missing anything and thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you see Picture Library drop-down there in web-part properties?

Comment: Is the picture library slideshow web part on a page that is on the same site as your picture library?

Comment: The Picture Slideshow Web Part is not on the same page as my picture library @ChrisG

Comment: I can see the "picture library" drop-down in the web-part properties @akbarali

Answer (score 1):

Configuring a `Picture Library Slideshow Web Part` is considered  straightforward settings , Based on your description , I didn't see you missed any step , so I suggest to

- Make sure that you have created a `picture library` at the **same site** that you try to use `picture library slideshow web part`
- Make sure that You have already selected a picture library , not another library type.

[image]

- Make sure that the current page does not have any custom javascript code, so try to configure `Picture Library Slideshow Web Part` at a page with default master page.
- If the issue still , try to use another Browser.

For more details check [How to Use the Picture Library Slideshow Web Part in SharePoint 2013](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/03/29/how-to-use-picture-library-web-part-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Comment: Link is dead...